# pjsua_aud.c .Unable to open file for playback: Not found (PJ_ENOTFOUND)

Tags: ubuntu, sip, voip, pjsip

I am running pjsua for python on Ubuntu 14, to make voip call. On make_call.py and answer_call.py I get ENOTFOUND error, unable to open pjsua_aud.c file. Have already tried

```
#define PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_PORTAUDIO 0
#define PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_ALSA 1

#define PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_PORTAUDIO 0
#define PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_ALSA 1
#include <pj/config_site_sample.h>
```

I've also tried editing pjmedia/build/os-linux.mak and setting AC_PJMEDIA_SND to a different value (e.g. alsa)

Same error each time.

Comment: @jcm We saw your solution on another post. Can you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The library most.voip calls the pjsua_aud.c from api_backend.py, in the api_backend.py the most.voip define the playback file :

```
line 53: voip_root_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../")
line 54: in_call_ring_tone = "data/sounds/ring_in_call.wav"   
line 55: out_call_ring_tone = "data/sounds/ring_out_call.wav"
```

When you install most.voip in any linux distribution the package is moved to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages it means that api_backend.py can not anymore find the playback files.

The solution is to copy the /most-voip/python/src/data folder to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

you can solve this issue with :

```
sudo cp -R /home/user/most-voip/python/src/data /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```